# How do I install IBM Access?

Tags: installation

I'm trying to figure out how to install `IBM iSeriesaccess_7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm` on Ubuntu 11.10.  I'm very new to Linux, but understand that I needed to run the `alien` command to convert the rpm to a deb file.  `Iseriesaccess_7.1.0-1.0_amd64.deb` was the result of me running the alien command.

I thought IBM5250 would launch the program, but that doesn't seem to be working.  If someone could please list the proper way to install `IBM iSeriesaccess_7.1.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm` and the command to get it running I would appreciate it.

I have followed the instructions given [here](http://www.allars.co.uk/2011/06/installing-ibm-iseries-access-on-ubuntu-11-04/) but nothing happens when I try `gksudo /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/bin/launch5250`. I'm not so sure this method works for Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: well I found these for Natty - should get you going :) http://www.allars.co.uk/2011/06/installing-ibm-iseries-access-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: I tried that but nothing happens when I try:                                                               gksudo /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/bin/launch5250.  I'm not sure if this method works for 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=165337), there is now a [project on sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ibm5250onubuntu/) that installs *IBM iSeries Client Access / IBM i Access / IBM5250* on supported versions of Ubuntu Linux (current version and most recent LTS, both 32 and 64 bits).

If you still want to install the `.rpm` package that you've got, you can check out the thread linked above. Following is the instructions to a script that does all the work mentioned in steps in the thread and the script itself.

> Just put the script and the `.rpm` in the same dir, get a terminal in
>   that dir, `chmod +x` the script and run the script, passing the
>   filename of the rpm to it as the first argument. The script works both
>   in 32 and 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04.
>
> Careful with quotes and such when using copy/paste. Best to just
>   download the script. Also. 5.4 seems to work better than 6.1 for me
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
>
> function usagedie {
>         echo '' 1>&2
>         echo "iSeries Client Access RPM Installer for Ubuntu" 1>&2
>         echo "Usage: $0 <filename.rpm>" 1>&2
>   echo "Example: $0 iSeriesAccess-6.1.0-1.0.i386.rpm" 1>&2
>         echo '' 1>&2
>   exit
> }
>
> function installit64 {
>   sudo aptitude install alien odbcinst1debian1 unixodbc libmotif3 msttcorefonts ttf-mscorefonts-installer ia32-libs -y
>
>   if [ -d /usr/lib32 ]; then
>       echo ''
>   else
>       sudo mkdir /usr/lib32
>   fi
>
>   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-15ubuntu4_i386.deb
>   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/o/openmotif/libmotif3_2.2.3-2_i386.deb
>
>   ar vx libstdc++5_3.3.6-15ubuntu4_i386.deb; tar xzf data.tar.gz; sudo mv usr/lib/libstdc++.so.* /usr/lib32;
>   ar vx libmotif3_2.2.3-2_i386.deb; tar xzf data.tar.gz; sudo mv usr/lib/libXm.so.3* /usr/lib32;
>
>   sudo alien --scripts -g $TARGETRPM
>   cd iSeriesAccess-*
>   sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b -d -ai386
>   sudo locale-gen en_US
>   cd ..
>   sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture iseriesaccess_*.deb
> }
>
> function installit32 {
>   sudo aptitude install alien odbcinst1debian1 unixodbc libmotif3 msttcorefonts ttf-mscorefonts-installer -y
>
>   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-15ubuntu4_i386.deb
>   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/o/openmotif/libmotif3_2.2.3-2_i386.deb
>
>   ar vx libstdc++5_3.3.6-15ubuntu4_i386.deb; tar xzf data.tar.gz; sudo mv usr/lib/libstdc++.so.* /usr/lib;
>   ar vx libmotif3_2.2.3-2_i386.deb; tar xzf data.tar.gz; sudo mv usr/lib/libXm.so.3* /usr/lib;
>
>   sudo alien --scripts -g $TARGETRPM
>   cd iSeriesAccess-*
>   sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b -d -ai386
>   sudo locale-gen en_US
>   cd ..
>   sudo dpkg -i iseriesaccess_*.deb
> }
>
> function cleanup {
>   cd ..
>   sudo rm -rf tmpiseriesrpm
> }
>
> function goodbye {
>   echo ''
>   echo "Script complete!"
>   echo ''
>   echo "Launch the program like this:"
>   echo "ibm5250 192.168.156.whatever -title MyFancyTitleBar -DISPLAY_NAME \"UBUNTUA UBUNTUB UBUNTUC UBUNTUD\" -LANGID en_US"
>   echo ''
>   echo "Uninstall the program like this:"
>   echo "sudo dpkg --remove iseriesaccess"
>   echo ''
> }
>
> if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
>         usagedie
> fi
>
> TARGETRPM=$1
>
> if [ -d tmpiseriesrpm ]; then
>         sudo rm -rf tmpiseriesrpm
> else
>   echo ''
> fi
>
> mkdir tmpiseriesrpm
> cp $TARGETRPM tmpiseriesrpm
> cd tmpiseriesrpm
>
> MYARCH=`uname -m`
>
> if [ "$MYARCH" == "x86_64" ]; then
>   installit64
> else
>   installit32
> fi
>
> cleanup
> goodbye
> ```